# Various issues installing igraph in Visual Studio 2010 and Cygwin/MinGW ("sys/time.h not found")

Tags: cygwin, mingw, igraph

I couldn't get igraph to work with Visual Studio 2010 (supposedly many known issues), and so decided to try installing it in Cygwin. `./configure` went fine. But `make` gave this error:

```
f2c/dtime_.c:16:23: fatal error: sys/times.h: No such file or directory

Makefile:2190: recipe for target `libf2c_la-dtime_.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [libf2c_la-dtime_.lo] Error 1
```

I tried installing it in MinGW and get the same error when I `make`. Should I be providing "sys/time.h" or a path to it? Where is sys/time.h? Using Windows 7.

**Edit**

The problems in Cygwin and MinGW was due to the wrong version of gcc being used by my clean installation of Cygwin (and a characteristic of MinGW). Solution here: [Installing/compiling in Cygwin/MinGW - How to set the include "path"? (symbolic link?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747515/installing-compiling-in-cygwin-mingw-how-to-set-the-include-path-symbolic)

The problem in Visual Studio 2010 was due to building in "Debug" instead of "Release". One of igraph's creator, Gábor Csárdi, graciously provided an excellent step-by-step guide below that identified and resolved it.

Comment: Which igraph version is this? Did you download the package specifically made for Visual Studio? See http://igraph.sourceforge.net/download.html.

Comment: @GaborCsardi - version 0.6. Yes I did download the one for Visual Studio. When I compile it in Visual Studio 2010, I get a lot of "conversion from igraph_real_t to int" warnings, which I conclude was why the library doesn't work. For Cygwin and MinGW, I got the one that just says "C library". Am I supposed to be doing more than "./configure, make, make install" for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igraph actually does work with Visual C++ 2010 Express, we test this before releases, and I have just tried it. You need to do the following steps.

1. Download the [source package specifically created for Visual Studio](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/download.html).
2. Uncompress the file into `My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects`.
3. Open the `igraph.sln` solution file in `igraph-0.6-msvc\igraph-0.6-msvc` directory from Visual Studio.
4. Visual Studio offers to convert the solution file to the current format, do that. Just click on Next, Next and Finish.
5. On the toolbar, change 'Debug' to 'Release' to make release builds.
6. Choose Debug -> Build solution and wait until the library is built.

To test it you can open the solution file in the `igraphtest` directory, convert it as well, choose 'Release' builds, and then build it and run it from the command line. It is a simple C++ program that uses igraph to create a graph and write it into the file `out.txt`.

You don't have to set up include and library directories at all, everything is set up properly in the solution file, both for igraph and igraphtest.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly now. Turns out that the problem was building in "Debug". Switching to "Release" fixed it. Will edit the question to reflect that very good step-by-step instructions for compiling in Visual Studio exists here.

Comment: Actually, the Debug build should work as well, ideally. I'll try to see why it does not.

Answer (score 0):

is there an `sys/times.h` file?

I have a vague memory that I had to make that symlink on a system once.

Comment: In my Cygwin, there is a include/sys/times.h. But not in MinGW. I copied times.h into the MinGW folder but then ended up with an "_ansi.h: No such file or directory" error. What keywords should I google for about this? Seems like people get this sys/time.h for various reasons not related to my case (from my googling).

Comment: Sorry, that's as far as I can help.