# Installing/compiling in Cygwin/MinGW - How to set the include "path"? (symbolic link?)

Tags: c, windows-7, makefile, cygwin, mingw

I have been trying to install/compile C libraries in Windows 7 using Cygwin and MinGW. However, I am getting errors like these during `make`:

```
sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
sys/times.h: No such file or directory
```

I previously thought it might be a problem with the specific libraries and asked here: [Various issues installing igraph in Visual Studio 2010 and Cygwin/MinGW ("sys/time.h not found")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737397/sys-time-h-not-found-error-when-installing-igraph-in-cygwin-and-mingw), but after encountering the same error with different libraries, I think the problem lies on my end.

**Attempt**

`cygwin/usr/include/sys/times.h` and `cygwin/usr/include/sys/resource.h` exists. After getting advice regarding symbolic links, I used `ln -s /usr/include/sys sys` to make sure that `sys/times.h` worked.

I went to look at the `make` output for a specific library (igraph). It says it entered a "src" folder. So, I went to the src folder and did the same thing: `ln -s /usr/include/sys sys` and made sure that `sys/times.h` worked within the src folder too.

However, I am still getting:

```
fatal error: sys/times.h: No such file or directory
```

**Question**

How do I set the "path" for `make` to find 'sys/times.h' or other files in the /usr/include/sys folder? What am I missing here?

P.S.

Please bear with me as I am usually a Windows user and not familiar with Linux terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much investigation, the problem turned out to be that:

1. MinGW does not have sys/times.h.
2. Cygwin has it, but my Cyqwin was using the gcc in my python
   directory, which is MinGW's gcc.

This was discovered while trying to resolve another problem here:

[Cannot compile C code with #include <sys/times.h> in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749529/cannot-compile-c-code-with-include-sys-times-h-in-cygwin)

So it turns out that my problem had nothing to do with the include path or making symbolic links, but rather, the gcc version/type was wrong. This fact eluded me because I was running a clean installation of Cygwin and didn't know that it would automatically use the MinGW's gcc in my Python folder.

Answer (score 1):

see http://mail.kde.org/pipermail/kde-windows/2006-May/000194.html
as they say even if the times.h is put there its functions may not be implemented by mingw

when running ./configure i'm getting this(its hard to notice)
[image]

so first try copying the times.h and then use ./configure and see if this error isn't there

Comment: Tried this. "fatal error: sys/times.h: No such file or directory" again. :(

Comment: Regarding your latest suggestion: The root directory of MSYS seems to be C:\MinGW\msys\1.0 and there is no way to go back further than this. There is "sys" folder in 1.0 or any of its subfolder. I am not sure now to do a "make -I\path\sys" like in that thread. Furthermore, I actually tried running "make -I\usr\include\sys" in both Cygwin and MinGW but still get the same "sys\times.h no such file or directory" problem.

Comment: Tried copying times.h to C:MinGW\include but ./configure still says sys/times.h usability... no and presence... no. Is it possible to obtain/install the stuff in "sys" proper in order to get sys/times.h?

Comment: Cygwin's /usr/include/sys actually has times.h in it but .\configure still tells me sys/times.h usability and presence... no! However, sys/types.h and sys/stat.h is "yes". I am guessing this is not a include/path issue but rather a problem with my sys/times.h?

Comment: sorry i couldn't help you.


if you have extra time try this 
get zenwalk linux live edition(comes with gcc) 
and create a virtual machine and launch zenwalk
use a usb-pen mounting or some other method to copy file or simply download igraph inside the vm
and try compiling there
doing so will only give you the knowledge of wheather it works on linux or not if it works you can try to download cross compiler and compile it there for windows

Comment: Noted. Thanks for all the help though! Much appreciated.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue (see my answer). But +1 for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Build libigraph with minGW without having "sys/times.h"**

That may be interesting for all building "igraph" and don't want to create it with "cygwin" but with "mingw".

In my "msys / mingw" environment, I have my "source code" in. "C:\msys\1.0\src" directory.
igraph dir. == **C:\msys\1.0\src\igraph-0.6**

- Run c:\msys\1.0\msys.bat
- cd to the top root **cd /**
- cd to igraph **cd usr/src/igraph-0.6**
  **Note:** There is no **usr** folder in **C:\msys\1.0\**. Take care do'nt create a **usr** folder !!!
- Type **./configure** Now the msys shell look something like

**Administrator@drserver-p /usr/src/igraph-0.6**
**$ ./configure**

- hit "Enter"

it takes a while.

**Change of files.**

- goto igraph-0.6\src
- Open with Notepadd++ or another editor the **"Makefile"**
  Goto line 832 or search for **libf2c_la_CFLAGS =**
  Put **-DUSE_CLOCK** after **libf2c_la_CFLAGS =**
  Now it looks like **libf2c_la_CFLAGS = -DUSE_CLOCK -DSkip_f2c_Undefs ....**
- Open **igraph-0.6\src\f2c\uninit.c**
- Goto Line 182 or serach for **_control87(EM_DENORMAL**
  comment this line **/* _control87(EM_DENORMAL ..... */**
- Open **igraph-0.6\src\f2c\s_paus.c**
  Goto Line 84 or search for **pause();**
  comment this line **/* pause(); */**
- Type **make** Now the msys shell look something like

**Administrator@drserver-p /usr/src/igraph-0.6**
**$ make**

- hit "Enter"

If it works it takes about 1 hour !

Answer (score 0):

you should check your makefile,   the CFLAGS/CPPFLAGS has -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS for windows.
in other words， you should never access the sys/times code branch on windows.