# Cannot compile C code with #include <sys/times.h> in Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

I was trying to install/compile libraries such as igraph and SNAP in Windows 7 using Cygwin (and also tried MinGW-MSYS) and I ran into some problems.

I think I have narrowed down the problem to this error given by `./configure`:

```
checking sys/times.h usability... no
checking sys/times.h presence... no
checking for sys/times.h... no
```

In Cygwin, `/usr/include/sys/times.h` actually do exists. I googled about this for MinGW and it seems that sys/times.h is not available for MinGW because "*the POSIX/BSD "times" function is not part of the ANSI standard and does not exist under Mingw32 runtime*".

As an experiment, I tried compiling this C code in Cygwin using gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

int main (void) 
{

      return 0;
}
```

This does not compile, with the error `sys/times.h no such file or directory`. This happens even when I change the include to `</usr/include/sys/times.h>` or `<usr/include/sys/times.h>`. In the Cygwin command promot `/usr/include/sys/times.h` work correctly.

**Question**

How do I get sys/times.h usability and presence? Is there a package or library I can install?

Comment: @H2CO3 - fatal error: /usr/include/sys/times.h: No such file or directory. But I think Jason (below) got the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code compiles with no problem on my Cygwin. Actually `/usr/include` is one of the default include search paths for gcc, so normally gcc should be able to find `sys/times.h`.

Perhaps you are using MinGW version of gcc instead of Cygwin gcc? Try `which gcc` to make sure it's `/usr/bin/gcc`, and also `gcc --version` to make sure it does not display like `mingw32-gcc.exe (GCC) x.x.x`.

You can also try to compile your C file with verbose output:

```
gcc -v test.c
```

It shows how gcc searches include files. `/usr/include` should be one of the search path list if you use Cygwin's gcc.

Comment: `which gcc` gives `/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/gcc`! `gcc -v test.c` shows that its searching in my python27 mingw folders! (?!) Thanks! I think we found the problem. How do I get Cygwin to use the correct version?

Comment: Look at your PATH variable: `echo $PATH`. Make sure `/usr/bin` comes earlier than `/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts`. If not, you need to modify your Cygwin ~/.bashrc and/or your Windows PATH environment variable. The simpliest way may be just put this line in the top of your ~/.bashrc: `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it identified the problem. I am still trying to figure out how to edit $PATH, which from what I googled is not easy and will take some time to learn. But thank you so much for your input, I was stuck for so long on this. +1!

Comment: Thank you! I would never find that I use MinGW compiler instead of cygwin-gcc without your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Legendre Edit $PATH by going to Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables. Here you can edit any environment variable including PATH. It actually is quite easy, each variable is just a string of semi-colon separated paths.

Answer (score 2):

As I found out, there seems to be some intrinsic problems with this issue, and sys/times.h is not supposed to be used under windows (not supported for some reason).

As I mentioned also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003250/compile-for-jni-in-windows-7/15177658#15177658), it's use should actually be removed from the code to make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Delete the folder C:\cygwin64 . Reinstall cygwin. Choose all defaults but when you get to 'Select Packaages', make sure to search and select the following one by one: binutils , make , gcc-g++ . For each one, select the dropdown and change form 'skip' to the newest version. Continue until you complete the installation. Everything worked for me from there.