# Compile for JNI in windows 7

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface, cygwin

I am trying to compile an open source project called [jbliss](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/jbliss-0.50beta2.zip) as a DLL under windows 7, so that I can use it with JNI in Java. Everything works fine in Linux using the makefile already provided in the package.

My first search pointed me to cygwin, and then I followed several suggestions, like [this one](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html), which basically tells me to use:

```
gcc-3 -D __int64="long long" -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias 
  -I"<JAVA_HOME>\include" -I"<JAVA_HOME>\include\win32" -shared -o jbliss.dll *.cc
```

This brings me mainly to the following error:

```
bliss-0.50/timer.cc:2:23: sys/times.h: No such file or directory
```

I googled this error, and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749529/cannot-compile-c-code-with-include-sys-times-h-in-cygwin), which suggests to use `-I  /usr/include/`. But that will cause more errors than it solves:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:66,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/3.4.4/include/c++/set:66,
                 from bliss-0.50/graph.cc:4:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdlib:181: error: `::strtold' has not been declared
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdlib:200: error: `__gnu_cxx::strtold' has not been declared
```

So I am sitting now puzzled and hoping for an answer, which options of gcc to use to get it right.
I have just downloaded cygwin and I would say I have the lastest version.

Thanks in advance.

---

Extra local information:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/WATCOM/BINNT:/cygdrive/c/WATCOM/BINW:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime Alternative/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2011b/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2011b/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSH/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz 2.28/bin
```

Comment: And **do** you actuallly have `sys/times.h` somewhere in the mingw32 include tree? If yes, then it's a problem of gcc environment. If not, then it's a problem of mingw installation.

Comment: The files exists at /usr/include/sys/times.h. What do you think I can do now? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show `which gcc` and the content of your PATH variable. Add it to your question.

Comment: There seems to be some incompatibility between the headers in /usr/include and the other things gcc is considering, because adding the compiler option `-I /usr/include` I will get the following basic error even before the compiler does anything else:  error: `::strtold' has not been declared

Comment: I suggest compiling a simple `test.c` with just `#include <sys/times.h>` by doing `gcc -v test.c`. No JNI dependency. First, you'll see what include path your gcc is trying to use, secondly you'll find out whether by chance the JNI includes hasn't broke anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling further shows me the fact that indeed sys/times.h is not (and apparently is not supposed to be) available on mingw. The include files under sys/times.h are said to be platform dependent and therefore not supported on windows.

The solution is to remove any call to sys/times.h (or any platform dependent library) as far as possible. Removing these include files (and of course adding proper options to the compiler) leads to a successful build.