# What is an alternative to including sys/times.h on windows?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, cross-platform, sys

## Background

I am trying to compile some code on windows that has previously been compiled on QNX.  According to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749529/cannot-compile-c-code-with-include-sys-times-h-in-cygwin) and this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003250/compile-for-jni-in-windows-7/15177658#15177658), I can resolve this issue by simply removing the include statements for sys/times.h.  When I remove the includes, I get a bunch of errors saying that variables have not been defined within the scope.  I assume this is because I have removed the include call.

## Question

What is an alternative to using sys/times.h in the code so I can use it on windows?

## Attempted Solutions

- Download & install cygwin to compile code - I cannot download cygwin due to network restrictions.  I would prefer not to have to download cygwin on my home network

Answer (score 1):

Here's how one project solved the problem:

https://code.google.com/p/madp-win/source/browse/src/include/sys/times.h?r=4ef496e2071896b295262c89eb36a8b3d7656bae

They use various includes available on Windows to fill in most of it, and define the rest themselves.  You may have to dig in the codebase a bit if you want to see the implementations for the other two functions - note that the library is LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

According to the questions you linked `sys/times.h` is only supported in cygwin and not in MinGW. They also indicate that if you can't use cygwin your only recourse is to rewrite the calls to use a standard Windows API instead, and remove the include of `sys/times.h`.