# Fast Artificial Neural Network Library On Embedded Platform

Tags: c, fann, mbed

Since this is my first question after years of finding answers in this site, id like to say a big thanks to everyone.

I want to use [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) in an embedded platform, and i am using UVision 4 to code in C.
Since i am a C/C++ rookie, i cant figure out if i can / how i can use that library.
When i try to simply include the files, i get this error:

FANN\fann.h(51): error:  #5: cannot open source input file "sys/time.h": No such file or directory

which makes sense because i am not compiling for windows platform.

Can i use the FANN library for embedded C? If so, how to include it?

Thanks

Comment: uh ... WHAT? sys/time.h is a UNIX library - has nothing to do with windows .... !

Comment: @specializt oh, it seems i got confused because the latter choice was for windows. Thanks.

Comment: .... "choice"? What?

Comment: something like, if we are not on windows use sys/time.h, else windows.h and other things

Comment: What? Your words dont make much sense ...

Comment: The following lib could help you: https://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-neural-networks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own "sys/time.h" for your embedded system. It must offer everything the original one does to be compatible with your external library. Wether you write one from scratch or wrap something around an existing code base which is compatible to your embedded device is up to you.

You can also have a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741553/what-is-an-alternative-to-including-sys-times-h-on-windows).

Comment: thats the exact opposite of what he was asking about - he is NOT using windows.

Comment: Turns out there was already one for my platform, <time.h> but i still need to define the timeval struct

Comment: your distribution is non-standard and ... apparently somewhat faulty.

Comment: Can you explain why it's the exact opposite of what he was asking about? Yes, the linked answer is about porting from unix to windows, but the solution's approach applies nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not compiling on windows you'll have no problem - simply include sys/time.h like this :

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```

Note the `<` and `>` character, these will make sure that your header is looked up within `$PATH`.
If your compiler still wont find that header you will need to install `libc`, on debian this can be done with tools like `apt-get`

Comment: It was this way, turns out on my platform it should be <time.h>, but still has no timeval struct defined.

Comment: that is ... _VERY_ weird and abnormal since the timeval struct is defined in there - if it isnt you will most likely run into major problems since your desitribution apparently is non-standard. Maybe think about switching to Debian or some other standard distribution, these will have libraries in which the timeval strict is defined.

Comment: It is for ARM microcontrollers, i guess thats why its lacking several things

Comment: ... debian has ARM support - whilst being pretty much GNU standard .... just saying.