# Compiling HDF5 API Using Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw, fortran, hdf5

I have been trying to install the HDF5 API in Windows using MinGW and Cygwin. I have given up on MinGW (after failing to compile HDF5-1.8.11 on it) because I need to use HDF5 on Fortran.

Using Cygwin with HDF5-1.8.11 produces errors when running the configure (bash) script and therefore it does not even start to compile. I read on [this link](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_Cygwin.txt) that the HDF5-1.8 compiles on Cygwin including the Fortran module. I downloaded an older version (HDF5-1.8.0) and the configure works fine, but the compile (2nd make) gives the following error:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/hdf5-1.8.0/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/hdf5-1.8.0/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC    --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -I/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/include    -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API  -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -MT H5Omtime.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/H5Omtime.Tpo -c -o H5Omtime.lo H5Omtime.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/include -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -MT H5Omtime.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/H5Omtime.Tpo -c H5Omtime.c -o H5Omtime.o
In file included from H5private.h:29:0,
             from H5Omtime.c:24:
H5public.h:154:18: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’ [-Wlong-long]
H5public.h:155:16: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’ [-Wlong-long]
H5Omtime.c: In function ‘H5O_mtime_decode’:
H5Omtime.c:194:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘tzset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
H5Omtime.c:194:9: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘tzset’ [-Wnested-externs]
H5Omtime.c:230:17: error: ‘timezone’ undeclared (first use in this function)
H5Omtime.c:230:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:813: recipe for target `H5Omtime.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [H5Omtime.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/hdf5-1.8.0/src'
Makefile:488: recipe for target `all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/hdf5-1.8.0/src'
Makefile:410: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I would appreciate any help on this! Thanks!

Comment: seems `time.h` might not be found. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749529/cannot-compile-c-code-with-include-sys-times-h-in-cygwin

Comment: Actually the configure script reports finding both time.h and sys/time.h

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error. It seems that the configure script sets a number of `#define` flags which indicate the presence of the `timezone` global variable, which in reality is not present within the cygwin environment and is thus reported missing in the error message. By removing the `#define H5_HAVE_TIMEZONE` from the header file H5pubconf.h I was able to get rid of this error.

Unfortunately, then still another error occurs during the make process, which can also be avoided by removing the `#define H5_HAVE_GETPWUID` from the same header file H5pubconf.h.

Although this does not explain what really went wrong during configure, with these two modifications I am able to successfully compile the library.