# Specifying a compiler in ./configure

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, configure

I'm trying to compile the igraph C library under Cygwin. I ran `./configure` and `make`, but `make` terminated with the following error:

```
fatal error: sys/times.h: No such file or directory
```

I searched on here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749529/cannot-compile-c-code-with-include-sys-times-h-in-cygwin), which allowed me to identify that, even from within Cygwin bash, the compiler was using my Mingw GCC instead of Cygwin GCC. In that question, the recommended solution is just to use the Cygwin compiler instead, but in that example the poster was compiling code they'd written themselves.

In my case, I presume there are a few lines I could change in the configured `Makefile`, but I'm not very comfortable with this sort of thing. I decided to try re-configuring with `./configure CC="/C/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe`, but that failed with `configure error: C compiler cannot create executables.` It said to see `config.log` for details, so I included the complete text of that file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by igraph configure 0.7.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure CC=/c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = JennaPC
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.19(0.48/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.2
uname -v = 2016-07-13 17:45

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/
PATH: /c/Windows/system32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
PATH: /c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/PDFtk/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.dnx/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit/
PATH: /c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/system32
PATH: /c/WINDOWS
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Anaconda3
PATH: /c/Anaconda3/Scripts
PATH: /c/Anaconda3/Library/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/Git/cmd
PATH: /c/Ruby23-x64/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/
PATH: /c/Python27
PATH: /c/Python27/Scripts
PATH: /c/Users/JennaR/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /c/w32tex/bin
PATH: /c/w32tex/bin64
PATH: /c/FCIV
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Dr. Memory/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Debuggers/x64


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2580: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2648: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2659: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2714: result: yes
configure:2865: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2904: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2911: checking for gawk
configure:2927: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2938: result: gawk
configure:2949: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2971: result: yes
configure:3000: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3017: result: yes
configure:3262: checking for gcc
configure:3289: result: /c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe
configure:3518: checking for C compiler version
configure:3527: /c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3538: $? = 0
configure:3527: /c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.4.0-1.i686/src/gcc-5.4.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.4.0-1.i686/src/gcc-5.4.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) 
configure:3538: $? = 0
configure:3527: /c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3538: $? = 1
configure:3527: /c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3538: $? = 1
configure:3558: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3580: /c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe    conftest.c  >&5
C:/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:3584: $? = 1
configure:3622: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "igraph"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "igraph"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "igraph 0.7.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "csardi.gabor@gmail.com"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "igraph"
| #define VERSION "0.7.1"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3627: error: in `/c/lib/igraph-0.7.1':
configure:3629: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=/c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='/c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /c/lib/igraph-0.7.1/missing aclocal-1.14'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /c/lib/igraph-0.7.1/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /c/lib/igraph-0.7.1/missing autoheader'
AUTOM4TE=''
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /c/lib/igraph-0.7.1/missing automake-1.14'
AWK='gawk'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
build=''
CC='/c/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
FLOATSTORE=''
GREP=''
HAVE_TLS=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
host=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
install_sh='${SHELL} /c/lib/igraph-0.7.1/install-sh'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INTERNAL_ARPACK_FALSE=''
INTERNAL_ARPACK_TRUE=''
INTERNAL_BLAS_FALSE=''
INTERNAL_BLAS_TRUE=''
INTERNAL_F2C_FALSE=''
INTERNAL_F2C_TRUE=''
INTERNAL_GLPK_FALSE=''
INTERNAL_GLPK_TRUE=''
INTERNAL_LAPACK_FALSE=''
INTERNAL_LAPACK_TRUE=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /c/lib/igraph-0.7.1/missing makeinfo'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
OTOOL=''
OTOOL64=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='csardi.gabor@gmail.com'
PACKAGE_NAME='igraph'
PACKAGE_STRING='igraph 0.7.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='igraph'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.7.1'
PACKAGE='igraph'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE='-lxml2 -lz -lm'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
RANLIB=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
VERSION='0.7.1'
WARNING_CFLAGS=''
WERROR_CFLAGS=''
XML2_CFLAGS=''
XML2_LIBS=''
XML2CONFIG=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "igraph"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "igraph"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "igraph 0.7.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "csardi.gabor@gmail.com"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "igraph"
#define VERSION "0.7.1"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Try: `./configure CC="C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe"`

Comment: I did try putting quotes around it - I just retried it and I got the same error

Comment: How about `./configure CC="/C/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe"`?

Comment: Still the same error, which is strange because as far as I can tell from looking at the config.log, it does look like that solved the problem of the slashes being removed

Comment: Please update the question with the exact config command and config log after your changes.

Comment: updated - thanks a lot for your help so far

Comment: Suggest reading the config log more carefully going forward. The error is now different: `C:/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Generally I debug these issues by manually running the config steps. In this case, copy the C code in the config log step that failed and run the gcc command exactly as shown in the log.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that - I removed the CC="..." and just moved cygwin above mingw in my path and that seems to have eliminated any issues, somehow